# How to refer to the corner of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a node suffix for the corners of a node?

I'd like the brace in this example to go from the lower-left corner of the first box to the lower-right corner of the last.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{frame} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
        text width=4em, text centered, minimum height=3em, node distance=3cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [frame] (f1) {$f_1$};
        \node [frame, right of=f1] (f2) {$f_2$};
        \node [frame, right of=f2] (f3) {$f_3$};
        \draw [decoration={brace,mirror},decorate] (f1.center) -- (f3.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: The corners are compass points: `south west` is the lower left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `south east` and `south west` anchors (details on page 308 of [TikZ](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) manual):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{frame} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
        text width=4em, text centered, minimum height=3em, node distance=3cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [frame] (f1) {$f_1$};
        \node [frame, right of=f1] (f2) {$f_2$};
        \node [frame, right of=f2] (f3) {$f_3$};
        \draw [decoration={brace,mirror},decorate] (f1.south west) -- (f3.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: If you have an unknown number of boxes you would like to underbrace, you can also use fit library of tikz which will create a box for you encompassing any number of given boxes (then, you can use south west and south east on this box).